# React Typescript requires to override render() method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a nx monorepo project with react frontend component. I have started writing the components in jsx format, then changed to typescript by adding types where needed and changing filenames to .tsx.

In my .tsx files I have some code in classes and some in javascript functions. The code that is in classes is throwing a strange error on compilation:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBkL4.png)

Here is my code:

App.tsx:

```
class App extends React.Component<unknown, AppState> {
  static contextType = UserContext;
  context!: React.ContextType<typeof UserContext>;

  constructor(props: unknown) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = ({
      sidebarOpen: false,
      currPage: 'Players',
    });
    this.navbarClick = this.navbarClick.bind(this);
    this.openSidebar = this.openSidebar.bind(this);
    this.closeSidebar = this.closeSidebar.bind(this);
    this.setSidebarOpen = this.setSidebarOpen.bind(this);
    this.setCurrPage = this.setCurrPage.bind(this);
  }

  setSidebarOpen(param: boolean) {
    this.setState({
      sidebarOpen: param,
    });
  }

  setCurrPage(param: string) {
    this.setState({
      currPage: param,
    });
  }

  navbarClick(choice: string) {
    this.setCurrPage(choice);
  }

  openSidebar() {
    this.setSidebarOpen(true);
  }

  closeSidebar() {
    this.setSidebarOpen(false);
  }
 

  /* The Application first checks for a valid token, if doesn't exist, display the login component until token is valid.
     The Application renders 3 windows to screen: sidebar, navbar and main window. There is a state param currPage
     which is updated from Navbar and responsible to re-render the Main component with the appropriate page
  */
  public render() {
    const { token, setToken, username } = this.context!;

    if (!token) {
      return <Login />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="sidebar">
          <Sidebar sidebarOpen={this.state.sidebarOpen} closeSidebar={this.closeSidebar} username={username} clickFunc={this.navbarClick} setToken={setToken}/>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div className="navbar">
            <Navbar sidebarOpen={this.state.sidebarOpen} openSidebar={this.openSidebar}/>  
          </div>
          <div className="main">
            <Main username={username} page={this.state.currPage}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

main.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { UserContextProvider } from './store/user-context';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <UserContextProvider>
        <App />
      </UserContextProvider>,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

UserContext.tsx:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

export interface UserContextIntf {
  role: string,
  setRole(role: string): void,
  token: string,
  setToken(token: string): void,
  username: string,
  setUsername(username: string): void
}

const UserContext = createContext<UserContextIntf>({
  role: "",
  setRole: (role: string) => {},
  token: "",
  setToken: (role: string) => {},
  username: "",
  setUsername: (role: string) => {},
});

export function UserContextProvider(props: any) {
  const [role, setRole] = useState<string>("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");

  const context: UserContextIntf = {
    role, setRole,
    token, setToken,
    username, setUsername
  };

  return <UserContext.Provider value={context}> {props.children} </UserContext.Provider>;
}

export default UserContext;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem. it's a NX bug about a line in package.json:
 `"noImplicitOverride": true,`

got to your package.json and delete this line or assign it **false** :
 `"noImplicitOverride": false,`